# Probability of a Network Collision between 2 computers

Tags: probability

Consider a network with a bus topology where $2$ computers, $A$ and $B$, wish to transmit
messages at the same time. After a collision is detected each computer stops transmitting and waits for a random time selected from $\left\{1, 2, \ldots, d\right\}$. Upon waiting for the randomly selected time each computer checks the bus to to see if is free, and if so it starts transmitting again. If a new collision is detected the above process is repeated, until one of the processors is able to successfully transmit. Assume that $d = 3$ and that the value of $d$ never changes.

Assume that only computers $A$ and $B$ wish to transmit. After detecting the first collision...

1) What is the probability that there will not be a second collision?

There are $9$ potential outcomes as $d=3$ and $3*3$ possibilities exist since we are comparing $2$ numbers in the range of $\left\{1, 2, 3 \right\}$. There is a $1/3$ chance of a collision, therefore the chance that there will not be a collision is $2/3$ . Is this correct?

2) What is the probability that exactly $k$ rounds of the above procedure are needed
before one of the computers can transmit?

Hint. During $k −1$ rounds there will be collisions and in the $k$ round the computers choose different random waiting times. Hence, the probability that $k$ rounds are needed is probability of a collision in first round × probability of collision in second round × · · ·

For this one I think it is $(2/3)^k$ because of the hint given.

What do you guys think? This is for a CS class, not statistics, so I am trying not to overthink it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the first part as there will be no second collision for the very next attempt. Then $\frac23$ is correct.

For the second part, it is a [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). We need $k-1$ failures followed by $1$ success.

Hence
$$\left( \frac13\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac23 \right)=\frac{2}{3^k}$$